# Why do my accelerometers respond so slowly?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, accelerometer

I'm asking them at 50Hz / 50 times per second for data. When I suddenly flip the device on the x-axis by 90 degrees while the device was flat on a table with display facing up bevore, the values move pretty slowly to the "target" value for that position.

Now the weird thing is: If I increase the measurement-rate, the value will move faster to that new value upon suddenly flipping the device by 90 degrees. But if I just ask once per second for the new value, it take's very long until the value reaches the target. What can be the reason for this?

I don't do any kind of data aggregation, and don't accumulate anything. I just do some simple filtering to get rid of the noise. My method looks like this:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    // Use a basic low-pass filter to only keep the gravity in the accelerometer values for the X and Y axes
    // accelerationX is an instance variable
    accelerationX = acceleration.x * 0.05 + accelerationX * (1.0 - 0.05);

    // round
    int i = accelerationX * 100;
    float clippedAccelerationValue = i;
    clippedAccelerationValue /= 100;

    [self moveViews:clippedAccelerationValue];
}
```

later on, in my -moveViews: method, I do this:

```
-(IBAction)moveSceneForPseudo3D:(float)accelerationValue {
    if(fabs(lastAccelerationValue - accelerationValue) > 0.02) { // some little treshold to prevent flickering when it lays on a table
        float viewAccelerationOffset = accelerationValue * 19 * -1;

        newXPos = initialViewOrigin + viewAccelerationOffset;
        myView.frame = CGRectMake(newXPos, myView.frame.origin.y, myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height);

        lastAccelerationValue = accelerationValue;
    }
}
```

As a result, of the device gets turned 90 degrees on the x-achsis, or 180 degrees, the view just moves pretty slowly to it's target position. I don't know if that's because of the physics of the accelerometers, or if it's a bug in my filtering code. I only know that there are fast paced games where the accelerometers are used for steering, so I almost can't imagine that's a hardware problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line:

```
accelerationX = acceleration.x * 0.05 + accelerationX * (1.0 - 0.05);
```

is a low-pass filter, which works by computing a moving average of the x acceleration.  In other words, each time that callback is called, you're only moving the `accelerationX` by 5% towards the new accelerometer value.  That's why it takes many iterations before `accelerationX` reflects the new orientation.

What you should do is increase the `0.05` value, to say `0.2`.  I'd make a global `#define` and play around with different values along with different refresh rates.

Comment: Thanks!! That was exactly the solution to the problem.

Comment: It should be added that the phase shift created by a RC LowPass filter (which this code implements) is significant. Other implementations of a low pass filter (such as one implemented using FFT) are a little better and that regard. They're much harder to implement though.